# open visual studio 2012 at a given line number and file

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to open a file at given lien number in vs 2012 but cannot get it to work

I have tried

```
devenv <filename> /command "Edit.Goto 67"
devenv /command "Edit.Goto 67" <filename>
```

but both open the file but do not go to the specified line

Does anyone know how I can achieve this

Thanks for your time

Comment: Works for me in VS2010 and VS2015. Used the second one.

Comment: Just retried with vs 2012 and still no joy